# Can I use Wayland on my nVidia machine?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, lightdm, wayland

I have a laptop with an nVidia RTX 2080 and the `440.64` driver. I have both `lightdm` and `gdm3` installed and am running Ubuntu 20.04 which means as of today I have just about the latest hardware, operating system and drivers.

My setup is one [Dell G7 laptop](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/dell-g7-15-gaming-laptop/spd/g-series-15-7590-laptop) and one external Dell 4k monitor connected to the miniDP port on the back of my laptop.

When I activate `lightdm` I have, in the extended login menu options, the option to use Ubuntu on Wayland.

Selecting this option and logging it only shows the desktop on the builtin monitor.

`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` shows `wayland`

However, nothing I can do allows content on my external monitor.  It is not detected by the "displays" option in setting (although unplugging and plugging it in does cause my *attached* monitor to blink).

Switching to `gdm3` and there is no gear / login settings that allows me to choose wayland.

My `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file shows wayland to be enabled. i.e. contents are :

```
# GDM configuration storage
#
# See /usr/share/gdm/gdm.schemas for a list of available options.

[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
#WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
#  TimedLoginEnable = true
#  TimedLogin = user1
#  TimedLoginDelay = 10

[security]

[xdmcp]

[chooser]

[debug]
# Uncomment the line below to turn on debugging
# More verbose logs
# Additionally lets the X server dump core if it crashes
#Enable=true
```

So two questions:

1. Why isn't this (running Wayland) working? The amount of research required to investigate this is significant.
2. As of today, using nVidia hardware, is there *any* possible configuration that allows Wayland to work (with necessary features like multiple monitors)

Comment: Is this a hybrid/optimus machine? (- In any event nvidia drivers do not work  or don't work very well in wayland..

Comment: I do not know if this is a hybrid/optimus machine.  Given that I could plug a monitor in the USB C port, I am assuming that it is a hybrid machine but I do not know if that is enabled.  Isn't optimus a software / firmware setting not a hardware option?

Comment: Open nvidia-settings (on X), see if there is a Prime Profiles section. Or install `inxi`', run this, add to your question `inxi -G`

Comment: There is a Prime Profiles section (currently set to Performance Mode).

Comment: This is what happens: On lightdm when you log into wayland you're automatically switched to the Intel iGPU, nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Gdm blacklists wayland when it detects nvidia drivers. This can be unset but the result will be the same, switching to Intel when logging in to wayland, again nothing to be done.

Comment: This is craziness.  Do you know where to express frustration to nVidia about their lack of Wayland support?